# Making a connection in Single User Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a third party vendor software that I have to call in an SQL Agent Job to restore my databases.  So my first step is to set the database in single user mode, my second step is to call the software to start the restore.  The problem is, the software takes so long to actually start the restore (its doing it all across the network) that another user can swoop in and take over the database.

Is there a way to put the DB in single user mode and then grab that connection right away?  I have tried with a few "Select Getdate()" but I feel that is taking it from the system, and not the database.  Do I have to select from a specific table in the database to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than place the database in single user mode, take the database offline in the context of another database:

```
USE tempdb;
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseToRestore
    SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Client Application Name" option along with the "-m" option that places SQL into single user mode.

That way only an application that matches the name given can connect and take the connection. Obviously you need to ensure that your client process that's doing the restore has a distinct name!

See here for info on the various SQL Server startup options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx

Also, I was under the impression you had to be an admin to connect in single user mode, which of course your normal users should not be. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong on that point!

Comment: Non-privileged users can access a database in `SINGLE_USER` mode, although only the first is allowed access.  Perhaps you are thinking of `RESTRICTED_USER`?

Comment: That will set the whole instance in Single User Mode, I need to be able to do it DB by DB.

Comment: Ah yes you're right - to be honest I didn't know you could put an individual DB into single user mode, so I didn't really notice that detail in your question. Dan's answer looks good, hopefully it works for you. I've learned something new too!